# Toggle Image on Mouse Up - Dragging Image Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm using JavaScript to toggle between 2 images. I'm using `OnClick` and `MouseDown` events to do this.

The MouseDown event switches to the blue bird.

The OnClick is supposed to switch back to the red bird.

The problem is if I hold down then drag the image and let go it doesn't change back to the other image. *as if it never fired the onclick event on the image.*

**Goal:** I want to be able to toggle / switch between both of the images even if I accidentally drag the image.

**Up Date**
Since there are a lot of complications toggling between the images using OnClick and MouseUp events. What I used a timer to show the image for 100ms then I would only use one event to handle everything?

[image]

```js
function BirdClick() {
  document.getElementById("Bird1").src = "https://media.giphy.com/media/3ornjQQZhry6bF31CM/giphy.gif";
}

//Mouse-Down
function BirdHit() {
  document.getElementById("Bird1").src = "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/1112/posts/25209/image/animate-bird-slide-25.gif";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3ornjQQZhry6bF31CM/giphy.gif" id="Bird1" style="width:100px;height:100px;" onclick="BirdClick()" onmousedown="BirdHit()" />
```

Comment: why `onclick` instead of `onmouseup`?

Comment: use on mouse up?

Comment: I tried that it does the same thing, but ill try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a mouse up event handler to the body to reset the bird to the first one.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', setBirdOne, false);
```

If you don't want the dragging of the image you can add `ondragstart="return false"` to prevent it.

**UPDATE**

Maybe is better to switch back to the first bird when your pointer leaves the image. That can be achieved with:

```
onmouseleave="setBirdOne()"
```

```js
function setBirdOne() {
  document.getElementById("Bird1").src = "https://media.giphy.com/media/3ornjQQZhry6bF31CM/giphy.gif";
}

function setBirdTwo() {
  document.getElementById("Bird1").src = "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/1112/posts/25209/image/animate-bird-slide-25.gif";        
} 

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', setBirdOne, false);
```

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3ornjQQZhry6bF31CM/giphy.gif" id="Bird1" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ondragstart="return false" onmouseleave="setBirdOne()" onmousedown="setBirdTwo()" />
```

Comment: Hi, If you drag the image downwards it stays on the blue bird.

Comment: @taji01 yes, is because the code runs in an iframe, is like if you go outside the window in a browser. You will not recieve any mouse events

Comment: Very Interesting! Thank you for your input!

Comment: @taji01 I updated the answer: if you add a `mouse leave` event you are sure that the image will always switch back to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to switch between these 2 image between mouse up and down. Also call the `getImage1()` to get the first image in `ondragend` and`onmouseleave` to handle drag event and the double click problem

```js
function getDrag() {
        getImage1();
    }
function getImage1() {
        document.getElementById("Bird1").src = "https://media.giphy.com/media/3ornjQQZhry6bF31CM/giphy.gif";

    }
 
    //Mouse-Down
    function getImage2() {
        document.getElementById("Bird1").src = "https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/1112/posts/25209/image/animate-bird-slide-25.gif";        
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3ornjQQZhry6bF31CM/giphy.gif" id="Bird1" style="width:100px;height:100px;" ondragend="getDrag()"  onmouseup="getImage1()" onmouseleave="getImage1()" onmousedown="getImage2()" />
<img src="https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/1112/posts/25209/image/animate-bird-slide-25.gif" style="width:0px;height:0px; visibility:hidden;" />
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this already and it didn't work. If you drag the image. It stay's on the same image.

Comment: No, Its just loading the image. try click once and then drag

Comment: Test it like this. On the current image drag it down and release. If you click on the same spot it will change, but if you drag the image it will act differently.

Comment: Another Test: It's gotten better, but If you double-click quickly and then drag it down and release. You'll notice the issue

Comment: See now it is rectified @taji01

Answer (score 1):

- On `mousedown` use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser drag-selections and other default stuff
- Use `mouseup` and `mouseleave` for the *hitEnd*

```js
var el = document.getElementById("Bird1");

var onHitStart = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent selections for drag etc
  el.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/v6Rlm.gif";
};
var onHitEnd = function() {
  el.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/R4RoF.gif";
};

el.addEventListener("mousedown",  onHitStart);
el.addEventListener("mouseleave", onHitEnd);
el.addEventListener("mouseup",    onHitEnd);
```

```css
#Bird1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="Bird1" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/R4RoF.gif" />
```

you can also add `el.addEventListener("mouseleave", onHitEnd);` to reset the state even if the mouse leaves `el`

Comment: Ahhh, almost :) like the person said below if you drag your mouse outside the window it stays on the current image.

Comment: Both you and TheGr8_Nik are correct. But TheGr8_Nik got the correct answer first so I will have to give them the marked answer. Thank you :)